# Browser downloading a background image that's already loaded on the page?

Tags: css, button, background, hover, preloader

I'm using a `<button>` element with a background graphic. I've applied the CSS psuedo class `:hover` to it to swap out the background with a different one. I'm preloading the background graphic elsewhere on the page.

Take a look at this JSFiddle for a stripped down demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WawV3/2/

In Mac Chrome (32.0.1700.77) and Safari (7.0.1), the first time you hover over the button, the background flashes as it (presumably) downloads the new graphic... even though that very same hover image is loaded further down the page. (It will only do this on the first hover; subsequent hovers load instantly. Reload the page to see it happen again.)

What gives? The browser shouldn't have to download the background image as it's already on the page in plain view... right?

Worth mentioning, this doesn't seem to be an issue in Firefox on both the Mac and Windows or in IE.

Comment: I haven't found an explanation for this behavior, however the popular workaround seems to be to use a sprite.

Comment: @j08691 Yeah... without getting into too much unnecessary detail, let's just say that sprites aren't an option in this scenario.

Comment: The image flashes when you hover over the button because the hover `background-image` asset is not loaded from the server until you hover over the button the first time.  You'll notice that if you hover over the button a second time, but image will not flash.

Comment: @Andrew Thanks. But you'll notice that the background image is already pulled down from the server to the page and displayed in a `<img>` tag. Should that land it in the browser's cache so it doesn't have to retrieve it from the server again?

Comment: You get the same flash result if you remove the "preloaded" `img` from the markup (in fact, you can see it appear in resources on hover). I'm a little out of my technical depth here, but I wonder if assets displayed in the DOM are somehow different than those called by CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can encode the background images to avoid this issue if using a sprite is not possible. See Fiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/WawV3/5/

```
button {
    height: 44px;
    width: 106px;
    background-image: url([data:image/png;base64,...]);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}
button:hover {
    background-image: url([data:image/png;base64,...]);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Seems like a good option. Two questions:
1. What are the downsides to this approach?
2. How did you encode the images?

Comment: The only downside to this approach is a slight increase in file size over a fully optimized sprite although this is offset by less calls to the server. To encode the images, I use a Mac app called Base64 Image Encoder and but there are a number of other apps out there as well as some online solutions available.